# SSIS Expression to Merge Two Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have a .CSV import that I will be performing a series of Transformations on. 
The first Transformation that I need to do is to merge two City Columns into 1 column.

The data that I have looks like this.

```
| City1 | City2 |
|Wichita|       |
|       |Houston|
|       |Chicago|
|Denver |       |
```

The required output should be,

```
| City  |
|Wichita|
|Houston|
|Chicago|
|Denver |
```

I want to keep this as an SSIS Derived Column Expression so that I can tie it to the rest of the transformation that I need to perform.

I already went back to the vendor and asked them to correct the data, they denied it. Now it's up to me to correct the dirty data so that we can use it in a series of reports.

Thank you in advance for any support.

Comment: Just union them together.

Comment: will there all ways be a null value in city1 when city2 is filled

Comment: @user2615302, yes. There will always be a Null if the other is occupied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a derived column to replace city 1. The formula would look something like City1 == "" ? City2 : City 1

Comment: This worked, I had to flip the columns though. Found some new data in City 1 (Suit Numbers) so I just put everything into City 2. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You might try the unpivot transformation. But that may leave you with some blank rows to clean up.

Another possibility would be simulating a coalesce function. [[reference](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/50a9955d-07c4-4ab5-b2eb-ed69f7feaa28/how-to-use-coalesce-function-in-derived-column-component)]

Answer (score 0):

try

```
select city1 as city
    from Table 
    where city1 not null
    union all
    select city2 as city
    from Table 
    where city2 not null
```